# How to force a page-break on weasyprint?

Tags: css, django, django-templates, weasyprint

I wonder if its possible to create a force break that splits the table rows? I think weasyprint does this in a sense but I want to break the rows in to specific counts (e.g 6 rows per page). Is that possible? I tried something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Header1</th>
        <th>Header2</th>
    </tr>
    {% for d in data %}
        {% if forloop.counter == 6 %}
          <p style="page-break-before: always;"></p>
        {% endif %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ d.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ d.age }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

but it just break each row in different pages. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Try with style attribute on tr element without adding any p element :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Header1</th>
        <th>Header2</th>
    </tr>
    {% for d in data %}
        <tr
        {% if forloop.counter == 6 %}
          style="break-before: page;"
        {% endif %}
        >
            <td>{{ d.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ d.age }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Note that page-break-before is deprecated : [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-before).
Note also that the result may not be really nice, you may have to add margin-top or something, and also some border at the beginning and end of each block of rows.